# Dynamic Group that can be pulled into summary measures Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

DAX is my enemy and I am struggling to parse solutions to similar problems and apply the learning. So if this is re-treading group I do apologise but am very grateful for the help.

I have a reference table that is the primary slicer for my entire Power BI file. This table has a repeated index for all UK local authorities (LA's) and their associated comparators. It looks like like:

| LA Index | LA Comparator |
| --- | --- |
| Barking and Dagenham | Southwark |
| Barking and Dagenham | Tower Hamlets |
| Barking and Dagenham | Lambeth |
| Barking and Dagenham | Barking and Dagenham |
| Barnet | Harrow |
| Barnet | Redbridge |
| Barnet | Enfield |

So a slicer will allow a user to select an LA from the `LA Index` but what we want is for the `LA Comparator` list. Then we want to select those `LA Comparators` when they appear in other data tables for the purposes of summary or a group. Acting a filter. So if the user selected `Barking and Dagenham` a table of population might then like this:

| LA | Average Pop |
| --- | --- |
| Southwark | 10000 |
| Tower Hamlets | 15000 |
| Lambeth | 4000 |
| Barking and Dagenham | 5000 |

But then summarise that into an average of `8500` that can be used in a Card or KPI visual.

Even better if I could use that grouping in something like a sunburst visual with the outer rings being the comparators and inner ring being the selected LA.

I hope that is clear. Happy to answer any questions anyone might have.